# Div won't take up rest of remaining space after setting html, body, .App, and #root to 100% height

Tags: css

Looks like the html element takes up the entire page, body has a little gap at the top for some reason, but my div still won't take up the rest of the remaining space.

Here's the html tree in the browser

[image: HTML tree]

App.css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: nunito;
}

html,
body,
#root,
.App {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HistorySheet.jsx

```
if (!loading) {
    return (
        <div className="historySheet">
            <Searchbar
                location={location}
                changeLocation={changeLocation}
                weatherData={weatherData}
            />
            <div className="backdrop">
                <div className="headers">
                    <p>Date</p>
                    <p>Avg</p>
                    <p>High</p>
                    <p>Low</p>
                    <p>Phase</p>
                </div>
                {results()}
                <img onClick={addResults} src={expand} alt="expand icon" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
} else {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
}
```

HistorySheet.css

```
.historySheet {
    max-width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.backdrop {
    width: 100vw;
    background: #468faf;
    padding: 1.5rem 17rem;
}

.headers {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.results {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I've tried doing min-width on everything, but it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want historySheet to have 100% width then you need to remove **max-width** from .historySheet

Comment: it's height that's the issue